# Two divs side by side

Tags: html, css

Basically, I'm attempting to get two divs side by side, here's the following layout I'm attempting to do.

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="search">

    </div>
    <div id="results">
        <h2>Waiting!</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS in which is positioning these divs they're side by side but pushed completely to the left of the page when I want them centred.

```
#content {

}
#search {
    float: left;
    width:​ 400px;
    height: 350px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    overflow: auto;

    -moz-box-shadow:​​ #555 0 0 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #555 0 0 8px;
    -o-box-shadow: #555 0 0 8px;
    box-shadow: #555 0 0 8px;
}

#results {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    height: 350px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    overflow: auto;

    -moz-box-shadow: #555 0 0 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #555 0 0 8px;
    -o-box-shadow: #555 0 0 8px;
    box-shadow: #555 0 0 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to center the wrapping div to center both of them. try it live here http://jsfiddle.net/dAVub/

```
#content {
    width:800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can center the container area using margin: 0 auto. Try this -

```
#content{ margin: 0 auto; width: 90%; }
```

This might helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this, but the most important thing is that you should set the `overflow` on your **container** appropriately when your inner elements float.  For example, you could just replace your CSS altogether with:

```
#content {
   overflow:hidden;  /* or auto, or visible */
   width:820px;
   margin-left:auto; /* not necessary by default */
   margin-right:auto; /* not necessary by default */
}

#content > div {
   float:left;
   margin: 10px auto;
   -moz-box-shadow:#555 0 0 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:#555 0 0 8px;
    -o-box-shadow:#555 0 0 8px;
    box-shadow:#555 0 0 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css

```
#content {
text-align:center;}
```

replace `float:left` with `display:inline-block;` in `#search`  and `#results`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abdulmalik/afSaG/)